# reg expression created from variable not working in .replace()

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a coding challenge that wants us to create a function that finds and replaces a word in a sentence.  I define the reg expression like this

```
//"before" is the parameter with the word to be replaced
var regRep = '/'+before+'/gi';
```

and I'm using it like this

```
//"str" is the sentence to search and prepAfter" is a variable with the replacement word.
var newStr = str.replace(regRep, prepAfter);
```

when returning `newStr` I get the original `str` without any modifications.  I went through and `console.log()`ed each of my variables and chunks of logic and the `replace()` method is the only thing not working as it's suppose to.  Here's the entire function.

```
function myReplace(str, before, after) {
    var prepAfter = "";
    var caseCheck = before.charAt(0);
    var regRep = '/'+before+'/gi';

    if(caseCheck === caseCheck.toUpperCase()){
      var firstLetter = after.substr(0,1).toUpperCase();
      var wordLength = after.length -1;
      var remWord = after.substr(1,wordLength);

      prepAfter = firstLetter.concat(remWord);
    }
    else{ prepAfter = after; }

    var newStr = str.replace(regRep, prepAfter);

    return newStr;
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

```
var regRep = new RegExp(before, 'gi');
```

If you pass a string to `replace()` (as you did), it will look for the actual string.

Note: if `before` is just a word in your case, you might not even need a regex, just passing it to `replace()` as-is could do. Depends on whether or not you need to check things like whitespace before and after.

Comment: yeah just doing `replace(before, prepAfter)` worked. Thanks